# NodeJS+Express: Multiple cross domain calls?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

So I'm looking for a way to keep making GET/AJAX calls on user input from somewhere in my client side code to an external address, for eg: `http://www.busbud.com/en/complete/locations/Ca?callback={fn}` and to return the body from that page.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery ajax method with JSONP as data type to make cross-domain calls.
I have tried it successfully for a facebook app on express.
http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/cross-domain-request-with-jquery-and-jsonp/